# Pyodbc Hive connection error in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, hive, pyodbc, pypyodbc

I am trying to connect to the Hive from Python with Pyodbc ,I have installed "ODBC driver for apache hive" and I did configured everything and the connection is good.

When I am trying to execute my query through pyodbc,i am getting below error.

I tried with "use native query " option in driver configuration ,and also given the schema name,but it is still showing the same error.

Error

> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42S02', '[42S02] [Cloudera][SQLEngine] (31740) Table or view not found:

Thank you

Comment: import pyodbc 

cnxn = pyodbc.connect(Connection string)

cursor = cnxn.cursor() 


cursor.execute("Select * from mydatabase.mytable")